# How to catch the user logout session when session expired in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when i login the on system it will catch the status Active Correct Working
when i Logout the on system it will catch the status Logout Correct Working

But I want to implement if Session is expired that time i want to catch auto Logout status??

Please help me how to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: There is `session_end` event in `global.asax`

Comment: As @Justcode says you can use session_end event. I would like to suggest another workaround but it may consume some more bandwidth. You can use  setTimeout() method of java script which sends ajax call to server every 20 seconds & check status about session expiration. Hope it helps.